# Android facebook login error

Tags: android, facebook

So, I have this code that works on every device so far, except my Huawei Ascend P6.

```
private void initFacebook(){
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    FacebookCallback<LoginResult> facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            handleStuff();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            handleStuff();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            handleStuff();
        }
    };

    loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, facebookCallback);
}



private void loginWithFacebook() {
    Collection<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, permissions);
}
```

After I log in, the app crashes and I have this error log:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:564)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
            at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onSavePassword(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:747)
            at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$1.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:157)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:931)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As far as I can see, my package name does not appear anywhere, so I cannot exactly trace where the error is in my code. 
The `BadTokenException` seems to happen when a `Dialog` is instantiated with `getApplicationContext()` instead of the simple `getContext()` or this.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your exception there is a **Dialog.show()** please check that or post those codes also

Comment: Thats exactly why I don't understand anything. There are absolutely no dialogs in my code. I think the only one that appears is the one from facebook

Comment: Ok. try using **YourActivityName.this** instead of **getApplicationContext()**

Comment: The only call to getApplicationContext() I have is when I initialize the FacebookSDK, and their documentation says I have to use getApplicationContext(). Anyway, I tried replacing that and nothing changed. I get the same error

Comment: Do you use a Dialog anywhere? If yes, you should check that activity is not finishing [[  if (getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing())  ]].

Comment: I have no dialogs in my code, the only dialog that appears is the loading dialog from the facebook sdk when I try to log in. However, on this device, it doesnt even reach that part of the code, so I see no dialog. The error appears regardless of whether I give the correct user and password.

Comment: I would check your device settings and see if your device is somehow destroying activities ... etc, I was suspecting [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276871/facebook-login-fragment-closes-application-using-facebook-sdk-3-0-1) but since you said that this works on other devices this I doubt it's related.

Comment: besides checking in developer options whether my device destroys activities, is there any other way? I checked this just now and they are kept. Also, on my other apps activities are kept, since the back button is working between them